# How do you call the methods of a class instance that was created in another class, from another class?

Tags: java, swing, class, methods

I am trying to create some animated game play text for my breakout game in Java Swing GUI.

**Expected behavior:** Everytime a brick is hit its points will Slam onto the screen, pause for 0.25 seconds and then fade up into nothing.

**What I have done:** A timer is used inside a method inside a class called `AlertText`. When the brick is hit in the class `GameLogic`, a new `AlertText` is created and its timers start running. Now in the Game Class I have the paint class.

**Question:** So how do I call upon the specific instances of `AlertText` that were created in `GameLogic` to use the setter and getter methods to set my `g.drawString` in paint in `Game` class.  I feel like this should be a common technique? Is there a name for it?

I got it to work with Global variables for one style of brick so I know animation is working, but I would need 100+ global variables to do every kind of brick.

---

Game Class

```
public class Game extends JPanel   
 {
 public static final int HEIGHT = 720;
 public static final int WIDTH = 600;
 public Color color;

private GameLogic gl = new GameLogic();
private KeyboardController  controller;
public Paddle player = new Paddle(110, HEIGHT-30, 100, 10, 10, color.black, controller);
public Ball gameBall = new Ball(300, 300, 15,  color.black);
private boolean PaddleUpdateComplete = false;

private List<AlertText> activeAlerts = new ArrayList<AlertText>();
Game game = new Game();



public void spawnNewAlert(Brick b){
    AlertText alert = new AlertText();
    alert.setxPos(b.getXPosition());
    alert.setyPos(b.getYPosition());
    alert.setText(b.getPoints()+"");
    alert.setColor(b.getColor());
    activeAlerts.add(alert);
    alert.fireText();
}    

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
     g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);


    g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, (int)AlertText.staticAlertSize));
    g.setColor(new Color(AlertText.staticRed, AlertText.staticGreen, AlertText.staticBlue));
    g.drawString(AlertText.staticAlertOne, AlertText.staticAlertXPos, AlertText.staticAlertYPos);

    player.draw((Graphics2D)g);
    gameBall.draw((Graphics2D)g);
    gl.drawBricks(g);
    // Draw GameObjects and anything else here
    g.setFont(scoreFont);
    g.drawString("Score: " + player.getScore(), 10, 25);
    g.drawString("LIVES: " + player.getLives(), 150, 25);
    if(gl.gameOver(player) &&
            gameBall.getYPosition() >= HEIGHT){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(endFont);
        g.drawString("Game Over!  Score: " + player.getScore(), (WIDTH/2) - 85, (HEIGHT/2));
    }
    if(gl.empty()){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(endFont);
        g.drawString("You won!  Score: " + player.getScore(), (WIDTH/2) - 85, (HEIGHT/2));
        timer.stop();
    }
    if(PowerUps.isMegaPaddle){
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.setFont(TimeFont);
    g.drawString(PowerUps.megaPaddlecount+"", 300, 500);
    }
    if(PowerUps.isMegaBall){
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     g.setFont(TimeFont);
     g.drawString(PowerUps.megaBallcount+"", 250, 400);   
    }
    if(!game.activeAlerts.isEmpty()){

        for(AlertText alert: game.activeAlerts){
        g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, alert.getTextSize()));
        g.setColor(alert.getColor());
        g.drawString(alert.getText(), alert.getxPos(), alert.getxPos());
        if(alert.count<=0){
         game.activeAlerts.remove(alert);
        }
     }

    } 
}

public void updateGameState()
{
    gameBall.move();
    player.move(controller);
    gl.checkCollisions(gameBall, player, timer, WIDTH, HEIGHT, game);
    gl.removeBrick();
    // Move GameObjects and check for collisions here
    if(Paddle.paddleHits==1 && !PaddleUpdateComplete){
        gameBall.setXVelocity(10);
        gameBall.setYVelocity(gameBall.getYVelocity()-6);
        PaddleUpdateComplete = true;
    }


}

public final void setupGame()
{
    gameBall.setXVelocity(0);
    gameBall.setYVelocity(-10);
    player.setLives(5);
    gl.makeBricks();
    // Instantiate instance variables here




}

// Constructor method should not be modified
public Game()
{
    // Set the size of the Panel to the correct size
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

    // Set the background color of the Panel to black
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    // Instantiate a KeyboardController and listen for input with it
    controller = new KeyboardController(); 
    this.addKeyListener(controller);

    // Call the setupGame method to initialize instance variables
    this.setupGame();

    // Get focus in the window
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocusInWindow();
}

// Start method should not be modified
public void start()
{
    // Set up a new Timer to repeat every 20 milliseconds (50 FPS)
    timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            repaint();
            updateGameState();
        }
    });

    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.start();
}

Timer timer; 
}
```

Alert Class method fireText()

```
public void fireText(){ 
  count = 50;
  textSize=0;
  Firing=true;
  Timer time = new Timer(50, null);
    time.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(count>47){
            textSize+=10;
            xPos-=2;
            count--;
        }
        else if(count>42){
            count--;
        }
        else {
        yPos -= 1;
        xPos += 1;
        textSize -= 1;
        count--;
        if(count<=0) {
            text ="";
            count=-1;
            Firing =false;
            time.stop();     
        }
        }

  }
  });
    time.start();      
 }
```

GameLogic method

```
public void checkCollisions(Ball ball, Paddle player, Timer time, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, Game game) {
    if(hitPaddle(ball, player)){
        ball.setYVelocity(ball.getYVelocity() * -1);
        Paddle.paddleHits++;
        return;
    }
    //check if ball hit any walls
    if(ball.getXPosition() >= (WIDTH - ball.getDiameter()) || ball.getXPosition() <= 0){
        ball.setXVelocity(ball.getXVelocity() * -1);
    }
    if(ball.getYPosition() > (player.getYPosition() + player.getHeight() + 10)){
        resetBall(ball, player, time, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
    if(ball.getYPosition() <= 0){
        ball.setYVelocity(ball.getYVelocity() * -1);
    }

    //handle collisions between bricks
    int brickRowsActive = 0;
    for(ArrayList<Brick> alb : bricks){
        if(alb.size() == horizontalCount){
            ++brickRowsActive;
        }
    }

    for(int i = (brickRowsActive==0) ? 0 : (brickRowsActive - 1); i < bricks.size(); ++i){
        for(Brick b : bricks.get(i)){ 
            if(brickHitByBall(ball, b)){
                checkPowerUps(b, player, ball);
                game.spawnNewAlert(b);
                player.setScore(player.getScore() + b.getPoints());
                b.decrementType();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some relevant code?

Comment: Swing or Android?  It can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you want a list of alerts in your `Game` class where the rendering is done, and you want to be able to add to that list in your `GameLogic` class where you handle all the gameplay.

There are a number of ways to do this. Assuming you have a reference to your `Game` class in your `GameLogic` then move the code for `spawnNewAlert()` into `Game`. Then your code in `GameLogic` can call `game.spawnNewAlert(b)` and then leave it to the `Game` class to manage.

You will need to add a few things to your `Game` class:

1. a new member field `private List<AlertText> activeAlerts = new ArrayList<AlertText>();`
2. in `spawnNewAlert()` just before you fireText(), add the alert to `activeAlerts`
3. in `paint()`, loop through `activeAlerts` and draw each one, remove any that are no longer valid (be careful about how you remove, either use an `Iterator` or defer the removes to after the iteration to prevent a `ConcurrentModificationException`.)

Comment: This is a good idea and i will try it, im a little confused on one thing - How will the paint() have access to the same activeAlert i am adding to? in order to call game.spawnNewAlert(b) in GameLogic wont i have to make a new Game in GameLogic? which will have its own seperate activeAlerts list that lives away from what the paint() can access? - i think i am mistaken on some detail of class mechanics here?

Comment: I had assumed `GameLogic` had a reference to the `Game` it was doing the logic for. If not, you can just pass it one when it is created and it can store it in a member variable.

Comment: ahhh, so i could add Game game to GameLogic constructor, i think i gotcha

Comment: is that weird to have a Class1 class1 actively in Class2 while the opposite is also true? seems like some kind of infinite loop could happen, ill have to turn this one over in my head a bit

Comment: i run into a stackOverflow error i will update the code

Comment: `Game game = new Game();` inside the `Game` class is your problem, you don't want that. Every time `Game` is created it make another, which makes another... on forever.

Comment: okay i made a new class just for spawner, i think im getting it down

Comment: Here: `private GameLogic gl = new GameLogic();`, you want to do this: `private GameLogic gl = new GameLogic(this);` and change the constructor for `GameLogic` to store that away. Although, I see you seem to have a lot of restrictions on the code (in the comments), so maybe you are not allowed to do that?

Comment: i got it working! thanks again. the code was originally for an old hwk assginment, but i am adding new stuff for fun

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to trigger a method in one object by another object both being wrapped up in the third, upper level one, right?

I would create both AlertText and GameLogic objects in the Game object and then pass the reference of the AlertText to the GameLogic, thus making it possible to the GameLogic to trigger the AletText's fireText() method. You would have to remove the instantiation of the AlertText from the spawnNewAlert method (in fact you need only one instance of AlertText), and rework a little bit the fireText method to reset after every run.

In GameLogic:

```
AlertText alert;

public GameLogic(AlertText alert //other parameters) {
  this.alert = alert;
  //other stuff you do here
}
```

In Game let's say:

```
GameLogic gameLogic;
AlertText alertText;

public Game() {
  alertText = new AlertText();
  gameLogic = new GameLogic(alertText);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
  gameLogic.spawnNewAlert(brick);
}
```